# Laravel 5 ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php for Routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a Model Class with name **Article.php**
and use below rout:

```
Route::get('articles/create','ArticlesController@create');
```

when input in browser http://localhost:8000/articles/create
i see this error :
**ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 125: No query results for model [App\Article].**

but when i user below every think is ok:(article insted article**s**)

```
Route::get('article/create','ArticlesController@create');
```

this is my controller :

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::all();

        return view('articles.index',compact('articles'));
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);

        return view('articles.show',compact('article'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('articles.create');
    }
}
```

what happened really ?!!!

Comment: You should include your `ArticleController`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with your code is that in your routes.php your route priority is like this :

```
Route::get('articles/{id}','ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('articles/create','ArticlesController@create');
```

and when you go to **http://localhost:8000/articles/create** in your browser laravel catches create as a variable with `{id}` request in `articles/{id}` before `articles/create` gets an opportunity to resolve the route. To solve your problem you must consider the route priority and make the following changes to your route.php file :

```
Route::get('articles/create','ArticlesController@create');
Route::get('articles/{id}/edit','ArticlesController@show');
Route::get('articles/{id}','ArticlesController@show');
```

But if you have a bunch of these in your routes.php file you should really consider using this instead:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

This single line will take care of all 4 get routes (index, create, edit, show) as well as all three post/put/delete routes of (store, update, delete).

But to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your controller code.

Most likely there's some code there that tries a findOrFail() on the Eloquent model, triggering this error.